# Eclipse Luna: After pushing commits to Bitbucket (using MercurialEclipse plugin) the amount of commits is not updated

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket, mercurialeclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna together with the MercurialEclipse plugin and Bitbucket. I can pull and push my commits. However, say I have two commits on my local repository. When I push the commits I can see them on BitBucket, however Eclipse still tells me there are two commits waiting to be pushed (see screenshot). Even after refreshing de repository in Eclipse the amount of commits waiting to be pushed stays 2.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks,

Paul

[image: ScreenshotWaitingCommits]